# Is there a way to load local video files in a react app?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

I have a huge collection of movies that I made through the years, so i'm building a webapp to have them classified and easily accesible. The app is mostly done, but I wanted to play the movie right from its page but I found some problems doing so:

1. First, I tried to made them play from a built-in player in the app, but players wont load the file if its not on the public folder and also it presents a problem that not every file is accepted in the player even if they are on /public
2. Then, I thought of just made them load on a new tab on the browser, but firefox (and I assume every other browser) doesnt allow it, I suppose because having a website running you local files on demand is a big security hole
3. My last idea is to launch VLC from the browser with the file url, but I have no idea on how to do this or if it's possible

Also, uploading the videos to the web it's not possible because of the size and also copyright problems, I want to keep the app as local as possible.

I'm running out of ideas on how to do this, is there a way to circumvent any of this problems or there's a way of doing this that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

One way is installing [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) .  with this labrary you can  add a file input that accepts a file then convert the file object obtained to a file path that can be used with `react-player`.

**A sample example :**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

export default function App() {
  const [videoFilePath, setVideoFilePath] = useState(null);

  const handleVideoUpload = (event) => {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    setVideoFilePath(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleVideoUpload} />
      <ReactPlayer url={videoFilePath} width="100%" height="100%" controls />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesnt the way I intented, this way i have to load the file manually instead of passing the url through arguments so i still have to browse my collection

Comment: the code provided is just a demo . you said you wanted to play the movie right from its page all you have to do is use the same logic  . instead passing `onChange={handleVideoUpload}`  use `onClick={handleVideoUpload}`

Comment: When i meant right from its page, i meant that i have movie profile, with its actors, director, etc, and a play button, that directly loads the file without having to browse it with an <input>, the path is provided through an argument